# How to differentiate Personal vs Corporate accounts in Twitter API?

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am currently attempting to match Yahoo Finance companies to their Twitter Accounts.

So far I am writing a script that does partial string matches of their company names to Twitter handles, and company webpages to the URL on their twitter accounts. This is imperfect and will sometimes match the wrong account

I was wondering if there is anything in the Twitter API that marks accounts as "Business" accounts.

Or any other clever solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing currently in the payload to indicate this would be the "verified" field on the [Twitter User object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users)

You could use `"verified": true` as a strong positive signal however, I would not consider `"verified": false` to mean much for you.

You could also use all of the above plus [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I can do three factor authentication with this as a stronger filter.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Twitter User object documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users)

*Some things to check for in the User object:*

#### Default Profile

If `default_profile` or `default_profile_image` are true then remove those default profiles.

#### Followers / Following

Does the account have a lot of followers? You can compare the number of following vs followers. Successful organizations will usually have more people following them than number of accounts they follow. This may or may not be definitive.

#### Website

Follow the website url inside `entities`. Is the WhoIs address on file for that domain a business or residential address? Maybe all those financial sites have something about finance on their website. You might already have a mention of finance, money or stocks in the `description` field of the User object. Does Yahoo Finance link to the same domain?

#### Entity Recognition

You could do some analysis on their user name, maybe some NLP to see what type of Named Entity it is. `ORG` for companies, agencies, institutions, etc. or `PERSON` for, well, a person. `NORP` and `FACILITY` could also be of help. Take a look at spaCy's [Built-in Entity Types](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition#entity-types) for more.

#### Scoring

Come up with all of your metrics and for the ones that are not definitive, try scoring them so that your most likely candidates have the highest score. You'll have to choose sensible numbers, use your intuition.

e.g.:

- *> 1000 followers* **+2**
- *followers > following* **+3**
- *"We are a finance company" in description* **+15**

---

Twitter has the [User object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users) documented quite extensively. There may be some other items you could look at and compare to determine what or who the entity is representing themselves as, in your case, finance companies. You'll of course have to find the accounts first to be able to verify them, but you could start by looking at who [Yahoo Finance follows](https://twitter.com/YahooFinance/following), it could be a bunch of nothing though, but you could also scoop up who their follows follow, and their follows, and ...

<sup>If you or anyone else have more ideas, please feel free to edit this answer.</sup>